# STS Error "The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer."

Tags: sharepoint-2010, x509certificate, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

So for starters, here's my environment:

- SharePoint 2010
- Windows Server 2008 Standard
- It's a VHD on my local
  machine
- I'm connected to my work domain I'm also connected to a
- VPN as well because some of the resources I need require it

So I have an STS in SharePoint for SSO

The STS is created via PowerShell cmdlets:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("c:\IdentityServer.cer")
$map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" –SameAsIncoming

# $map2 ... $mapN

$realm = "urn:mycompany:software"
$signinurl = "https://somesignin.com/FederationProvider/"

$ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name "MyFederationProvider" -Description "My Fed Provider" -Realm $realm -UseWReply -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -ClaimsMappings $map1 -SignInUrl $signinurl -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType
```

For the Internet Zone of my SharePoint site, I have the trusted identity provider created above as the Claims Authentication Type.

When I log in everything goes well until I hit this line in the code,
FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInResponse(signInResponseMessage, Response);

```
The error I get is:
Exception information: 
    Exception type: SecurityTokenException 
    Exception message: The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://mySharePointSite.com:443/_trust/default.aspx 
    Request path: /_trust/default.aspx 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: MyDomain\ThreadAccount

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 10 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\ThreadAccount
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTrustedIssuerNameRegistry`1.GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPPassiveIssuerNameRegistry.GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.CreateClaims(SamlSecurityToken samlSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.TokenReceiver.AuthenticateToken(SecurityToken token, Boolean ensureBearerToken, String endpointUri)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

However, the root certificate is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities in the MMC Certificates snap-in for the Computer Account on the Local Computer.
 As well, the root certificate is considered trusted in SharePoint. I added it via the Central Administration->Security->Manage Trust.

Any ideas why I'd still be getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the certificate being used initially was not from the domain I develop on. For local development a self-signed certificate was created and then the issuer was trusted. And this certificate was added to the manage trust store of my local Sharepoint farm, http://onpointwithsharepoint.blogspot.ca/2012/11/managing-trust-certificates-by-using.html.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an STS running at https://somesignin.com/FederationProvider/?

The documentation for New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer says that it "Creates an identity provider in the farm." This seems poorly worded to me. It doesn't actually create a new STS. What New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer really does is configure a trust relationship between sharepoint and an existing 3rd party identity provider. For example,

LiveID:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607628.aspx

or ADFS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446525.aspx

Comment: Yes, there is an STS running at https://somesignin.com/FederationProvider . If I'm doing development on my local, can I just create a trusted certificate for this instead of using the one the client provided me with?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, you can use your own certificate, just as long as it chains to a trusted root certificate, or is itself added as a trusted root certificate on the sharepoint server.